# How to use a variable as a property key inside an Object initializer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently, I am trying to localize my Chrome extension with various other languages and I am getting the variable message from _locales using `i189.getmessage` and then I want to use it inside a `const` Object dictionary. Below is the code:

```
var stad = chrome.i18n.getMessage("stand");
const emoji_map = {
  "__1_person__": "",
  "2 people": "",
  "3 people": "",
  "4 people": "",
  "stad": "sdss",
}
```

I want to use the value of the `stad` variable in place of `"stad"`, but don't know how to do this.

Comment: MDN documentation: [Object initializer: Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `[]`:

```
var stad = chrome.i18n.getMessage("stand");
const emoji_map = {
  "__1_person__": "",
  "2 people": "",
  "3 people": "",
  "4 people": "",
  [stad]: "stand",
}
```

Works fine for me:

[image: preview]

Comment: var stad = chrome.i18n.getMessage("stand"); gets the value standing from another file but when use it with double quotes it doesn't work any suggestions?

Comment: @rahulkapoor Double quotes? What does `console.log(chrome.i18n.getMessage("stand"))` give you?

Comment: it gives me -> standing which is what i want to use

Comment: What happens if you use the code I have in my answer? Remove the last trailing `,` and try? Shouldn't make a change but...

Comment: i want to use it in the place of stad and not in the place of sdss as you did any idea what to do?

Comment: thanks for this really appreciate it.

Comment: @rahulkapoor You are welcome mate!